# Carousel Bootstrap com imagens vindas de pasta do servidor

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <?php

        include 'conexao.php';

        $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE id='$imovelid';");
        while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $pasta = "painel/galeria/$linha[fotos]/";
            $imagens = glob("$pasta/{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.PNG}",GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach($imagens as $img){ ?>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <? } } ?>

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Ao gerar o slider com as imagens vindas da pasta, que está previamente cadastrada em um campo do banco de dados, o meu resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As imagens ficam empilhadas, ao invés de passarem uma por vez.

Já tentei trocar a localização de abrir e fechar div's, mas não tive muito sucesso.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Confira se está importando corretamente todas as dependencias do bootstrap

Comment: Obrigado pela pronta resposta. Tudo ok, `css` e `js` setados corretamente.

Comment: Eu não aguento! Para que negativar? Onde a pergunta é fora de escopo ou desnecessária?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É porque o teu `while` e o `foreach` estão fazendo o `<div class="carousel-inner">` se repetir diversas vezes, esse elemento **deve ser único** para cada carousel

Outra situação ser corrigida é que a classe `active` deve ser adicionada somente a um elemento por vez, ou seja você pode fazer uma variavel booleana para checar se já foi adicionado, uma if inline resolve:

```
<?php echo $primeiroActive ? ' active' : ''; ?>
```

Eu também suspeito que isso seja repetição:

```
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
    </div>
```

E pode ser removido.

Um exemplo corrigido e adiciona a checagem para o active:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- conteudo do carousel começa -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    <?php

    include 'conexao.php';

    $primeiroActive = true;

    $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE id='$imovelid';");
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $pasta = "painel/galeria/$linha[fotos]/";
        $imagens = glob("$pasta/{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.PNG}",GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($imagens as $img){ ?>

                <div class="item <? echo $primeiroActive ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
                </div>

        <?
        $primeiroActive = false; //Torna em false para não adicionar novamente o active
        } }
        ?>

            <!-- conteudo do carousel termina -->
            </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Grande @Guilherme Nascimento, obrigado pela ajuda. Infelizmente, não funciona. Ele fica agrupando as imagens, da mesma forma.

Comment: @CyberPlague tem um link online para eu ver, preciso ver como o HTML é processado e baixado.

Comment: Sem dúvidas, amigo: http://portolarimoveis.com.br/imovel.php?id=1

Comment: @CyberPlague achei o problema, vou editar a resposta :D

Comment: @CyberPlague adicionei uma variavel para que o active não se repetita e removi os elementos duplicados, me avisa se der certo ;)

Comment: Se existe um "cara", esse é você! Ficou demais!

Comment: @CyberPlague obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

O erro do seu código está neste trecho

```
       foreach($imagens as $img){ ?>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
        <? } } ?>
```

Perceba que você está fazendo o foreach repetir a `<div class="carousel-inner">`. Na verdade você precisa fazer com que o foreach repita apenas o bloco:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
</div>
```

Isso pode ser observado no padrão onde só repete o item:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

No qual o carrousel inner só aparece somente uma vez, para definer a primeira div: `<div class="item active">` você pode usar uma variável contadora $i:

Edit: Correção devido ao bug notado pelo @Guilherme Nascimento. Declarando a váriavel contadora fora do while não ocorrerá problemas e ainda sim definirá o primeiro item como ativo. Obrigado :D

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $pasta = "painel/galeria/$linha[fotos]/";
    $imagens = glob("$pasta/{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.PNG}",GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($imagens as $img){ ?>
        <?php if($i == 0) { ?>
            <div class="item active">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="item">
        <?php } ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="<?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo, @Marcelo. Foram duas respostas excelentes, de dois especialistas! Grato pelo seu suporte!

Comment: esse $=0; não vai dar certo porque o while vai reiniciar o $i=0 para zero toda a vez, se notar ele tem o while para os imoveis e o foreach para as fotos, então é IMOVEISxFOTOS=total de fotos. Só falta isso pra melhorar e o seu código ficará perfeito :)

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento pela dica. Já corrigi no código :D